# Exchanging messages when adding the second RSU

Tags: omnet++

I use veins-4a2. I added a second RSU in my simulation. My problem is that when I executed the simulation, the second RSU don't exchange messages with the nodes. Only the default RSU exchange messages with them.
In fact, i added this in  RSUExampleScenario.ned :

```
    **rsu[2]: RSU {
        @display("p=110,100;b=7,7,oval");
    }**
```

also I added the new RSU in "omnetpp.ini".
How can I adjust the code to allow the second RSU exchange messages?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the second RSU does not exchange messages? How did you conclude that it should?

Comment: I have concluded that the second RSU does not exchange messages because i didn't show in the window bellow of showing  messages traffic between rsu and nodes. I show only rsu[0] exchange messages with the nodes. Also during the simulation i do not show the rsu[1] that i have added change its color on green when it receives message.

Comment: Do you have a link to your (modified) scenario available?

Comment: I don't have a link to my modified scenario. In fact, i added this lines in RSUExampleScenario.ned : **rsu[2]: RSU {
        @display("p=110,100;b=7,7,oval");
    }**   and i added this in "omnetpp.ini":  *.rsu[1].mobility.x = 1500
*.rsu[1].mobility.y = 1500
*.rsu[1].mobility.z = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RSU is simply too far away to even be considered for receiving a frame.

If you move your second RSU to position `x=1800`/`y=1800` you will see that it successfully receives a frame as event `#996` (t=87.8s) and react by sending a frame as event `#3808` (t=87.8s as well).